# navigating past login page with Protractor

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor

I'm trying to write an E2E test for a page that requires a login.  To do this I am using `browser.get` to get the login page.  Then I am filling in the username and password using protractor.  Then I am attempting to use `browser.get` a second time to navigate to the page that I actually want to test.

```
describe('Macrosim Homepage', function() {
    it('should navigate to Manage Players', function() {
        browser.get('http://localhost:4444/simulate/lldev/macrosim');

        element(by.id('user_name')).sendKeys("fac_macrosim");
        element(by.id('password')).sendKeys("password123");
        element(by.id('sign-in-button')).click();

        expect(element(by.css('.navbar-brand')).getText()).toEqual('Home');

        browser.get('http://localhost:4444/simulate/simulation/lldev/macrosim/#/instructorManagePlayers');

        expect(element(by.css('.navbar-brand')).getText()).toEqual('Manage Players');

    });
});
```

When I watch my test run in the browser, I never see it successfully navigate to the Manage Players screen.  Also, my test fails with the following message:
Expected '' to equal 'Manage Players'.

Comment: What's on your config baseUrl? You should probably put `'http://localhost:4444'` in there for a start then start using relative paths with `browser.get('/simulate/lldev/macrosim')`

Comment: Anyway, looks like a timing issue, try putting `browser.sleep(5000);` before the last expect just to see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: Hey, actually it started working today.  I'm confused because I don't know why it was failing before.

Comment: Might be a timing issue, they're kind of random.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the manageplayer page is taking time to load.
Try to use a promise

```
var baseUrl="http://localhost:4444/simulate/";
var managePlayerUrl=baseUrl+"simulation/lldev/macrosim/#/instructorManagePlayers";
browser.get(managePlayerUrl).then(function(){
        expect(element(by.css('.navbar-brand')).getText()).toEqual('Manage Players');
});
```

Comment: I won't make any difference since Protractor already waits for each promise to be resolved before moving into the next as per the scheduler already contains the logic for that.